# Graph version of the PDE : $- \Delta u + \lambda u = 0$

Tags: graph-theory, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, graph-laplacian

Consider the (formal) continuous laplacian problem $- \Delta u = f$ on a bounded domain $\Omega$ with condition on the edge $\partial \Omega$.

In graph theory, a similar problem can be consider : $AU=B$ where the matrix $A$ is the **laplacian matrix asociated to the graph** and the unknown is a vector $U$ of size the number of nodes of the graph.

I found a lot of books and articles on this two problems and that emphasize their link and common traits.

I am looking for similar references, but rather for the graph version of the continuous problem $- \Delta u + \lambda u = f$ on a bounded domain $\Omega$ with condition on the edge $\partial \Omega$.

I guess the associated graph problem would be something like $(A + \lambda I)U=B$.

Do you have ideas of references that would consider these two problems and compare them ? Thanks for your help.